# Python append arrays of different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, 3d

I have a list of 15 files, all containing `N x D` values, with

- `D = 5` and
- `N` is specific to each file.

Is there any way to create a 3D array in python that is `15 x N x 5`?

Comment: What kind of files are they? Do they contain numerical values? How are the values separated in those files? What libraries are you using (e.g. standard library NumPy / Pandas)?

Comment: An array of array's creates a 3D array? What are you trying to create a vector? An array of vectors? a matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-dimension lists are very much possible in python. Consider the following example for your case specific values. `list3` is the parent list(the 3D list). while `list1` and `list2` are variable lists having variable N values and fixed D(5) values.

```
>>> N1=4
>>> list1 = []
>>> list1 = [5]*5
>>> list2 = [list1[:]]*N1
>>> list3=[]
>>> list3.append(list2)
>>> list3
[[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]]
>>> N2 = 2
>>> list1 = [2]*5
>>> list2 = [list1[:]]*N2
>>> list3.append(list2)                                                                                                                          
>>> list3
[[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]], [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't really have fixed length arrays. But you sure can create multi dimension arrays.

3Darray = [ [ [] ] ] # empty three-dimensional array.

You could just search for "python fixed length array" and "python multidimensional array" for info